# Error in conguring existing sharepoint installation to be use with tfs 2013:TF25043

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to configure my team foundation server(2013 preview) project to work with Our existing share point(SharePoint 2013).After install tsf2013.I have create the collection and team project successfully.
In order to show my tfs report on SharePoint, am trying configure SharePoint Extension for SharePoint product on TFS.On the First window of configurations it already indicate that the feature has being installed but need to be configure.
In the Configuration Process, i got this error:

```
TF25043:The readiness checks could not start.For more information,see the following logfile:C\ProgramData\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\ServerConfiguration\Logs\TFS_Sharepoint\Intergration_1106_115059.log
```

I have check this log but could not make any sense from it.Is my first experience.
Am doubting to post logfile information,it seems to contain alot detail about my server.pls help

Comment: If you can't post the log file, I would suggest contacting your Microsoft Service rep and using a service ticket.

Answer (score 1):

You have problem of connexion, check this in `administration console`, `section readiness checks`

Ensure that your Sharepoint and TFS are in the same domain.

[image]

Comment: ,they are actually on the same domin